# Reverse engineering and programming byte-by-byte on mobile OSs?

Tags: machine-code

I can't find any disassembling programs for the various binary formats out there that can run on OSes like Android, iOS, Blackberry, etc. These are the only devices I have access to, and I am trying to learn assembly and very low-level programming for retro-computers architectures (NES, SNES, Genesis, PSX, N64, etc.).

I managed to find one hex editor for Android that does the job well enough. It's entirely possible to load up any binaries there and hand-disassemble them (meaning look at each byte and an opcode table, etc.).

Doing so, is it possible that one can completely reverse engineer, say, a game and generate some form of assembly-textual source by stepping each machine byte(s) back to assembly instructions that can be re-programmed then back to the machine executable bytes/data/etc.?

What I'm asking is, is this possible or is there a step I am missing?

Comment: I think you should lookup the cpu type of your device, and check if it is in  [this](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/processors.shtml) list.

Comment: If you think it be useful if there was a disassembler for (Insert Platform Here), and there is none - or they do not work the way you'd like - then writing one is a good exercise. It will make you *intimately* familiar with the system.

Comment: I'd imagine that doing software development or reverse engineering on a tablet isn't fun. It's probably easier to buy some old laptop. But on question: Yes surely it is possible. Is it doable in an adequate timeframe? Hell no

Answer (score 2):

[Hex-Rays ported IDA to iOS several years ago](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=82):

[image: IDA on iOS]

It's not publicly available, but (from http://www.hexblog.com/?p=82#comment-652) --

> if you have a current ida license and want to play (just to
>   play) with it, feel free to send a request to the support

Answer (score 0):

[radare2](http://rada.re) is running natively on:

- Android
- iPhone
- [firefoxOS](https://twitter.com/trufae/status/379388265704742912)

If you don't like reversing on your device, you can spawn a web interface, and play around with your device, from your web browser, on your computer.

And it's a free software :)

[image: r2 on Android]